# Adapter in Android

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, android-arrayadapter

I just trying to set value to spinner manually by using `ArrayAdapter`,

```
String[] array_string = new String[5];    
array_string [0] = "1";  
array_string [1] = "2";   
array_string [2] = "3";

ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, array_spinner);                
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```

when i run this code the first element of the array_string i mean `(array_string [0] = "1";)` value alone displayed in the `Spinner` when i click `spinner` for list of items it raising **null pointer exception**.

Comment: Change these two lines, String[] array_string = new String[3]; and ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, array_string); Try this and let me know what happen..

Answer (score 1):

You have two null cells in the array (size = 5, set = 3), change this:

```
String[] array_string = new String[5];
```

to

```
String[] array_string = new String[3];
```

or assign values to `array_string[3]` and `array_string[4]`

Answer (score 0):

Well, there are 2 errors:
(1) your 5th line should probably be:

```
ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, array_string);
```

...i.e. `array_spinner` is not an array you declared in your snippet.

(2) You did not initialize all elements of array_string to an actual string immutable value. This means that `array_string[3]`, `array_string[4]` are null, therefore raising this null pointer error you speak of.